# Using SimplifyPolygon Class in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.6

I want to use the [SimplifyPolygon Class](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componentHelp/index.html#//0050000000qw000000) that existed in ArcObjects 10.3 in ArcObjects 10.6, but I cannot find it in 10.6.

How do I apply the SimplifyPolygon Class in ArcObjects 10.6?

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/467658/simplifypolygon-class-in-arcobjects10-6/467810#comment763901_467658):

> There was a change in how geoprocessing tools are called between 10.3
> and 10.6, you will need to use the geoprocessor interface
> https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IGeoProcessor.htm
> or use ITopologicalOperator simplify
> https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/10.6/net/webframe.htm#ITopologicalOperator_Simplify.htm